# Sidebar em um site feito sem CMS

Tags: php

Eu fiz um site onde possui um Blog. Esse site foi feito sem CMSs como Wordpress. Apenas no código puro.

Nos meus posts do Blog eu gostaria que tivesse um sidebar ao lado do texto. Exibindo somente uma prévia da página do Facebook.

Não sei se tem como fazer isso sem ser através de Wordpress ou qualquer outro CMS.

Se tiver, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Ja tentou usar o [Plugin de página](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin) do Facebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode utilizar o próprio [Plugin de Página](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin) do Facebook. Basta acessar o link e preencher o formulário com as informações de sua página:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Logo abaixo terá o botão **Obter Código** que gerará o código necessário, junto com os passos a serem seguidos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigado @Anderson. Deu certinho aqui.